# BGE double tap to run

Tags: game-engine

i'm beginner in python. I have follow Goran Milovanovic's tutorial about "key combo", in his tutorial he is using a text object which is just changing the text. I want to make a combo like double tap to make the object move. it's a been a while I'm playing on it, but still the code ain't working.
here's the code:

```
from bge import logic, events
import mathutils
import time

class Combo:


def __init__(self, delta, lst_keys):
    self.delta = delta
    self.keys = lst_keys

    self.cidx = 0
    self.time_last = 0

    self.complate = False

def main(self, hit_key):

    self.complate = False

    time_now = time.time()
    delta = time_now - self.time_last
    self.time_last = time_now
    print(time_now)

    if hit_key == self.keys[self.cidx] and delta < self.delta:
        self.cidx += 1
        if self.cidx == len(self.keys):
            self.complate = True
            self.cidx = 0
    elif hit_key == self.keys[0]:
        self.cidx == 1
    else:
        self.cidx == 0


def main():

cont = logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

keyboard = logic.keyboard.events
hold = logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE    
click = logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED
w = events.WKEY

moveW = own.worldOrientation.to_quaternion() * mathutils.Vector((0,1,0)) * 0.2          

up = Combo(1, keyboard[w]*2)
moveUp = own.localPosition = own.localPosition + moveW 
combo_label = [(up, moveUp)]

for c, l in combo_label:
    c.main(hold)
    if c.complate:            
            own = moveUp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the design of such a system.

## Requirements

- key pressed once -> start timer AND wait for second key press
- key pressed a second time AND wait for second key press -> do operation AND stop timer
- timer exceeds -> stop timer

(I guess this is what you want to achieve. If you want something else let me know).

## Design

This can be easily achieved via logic bricks. There is no point where you need Python.

Lets break down the requirements.

#### Sensing a key press

is simple: keyboard sensor

#### Running a timer

there are several options such as

- delay sensor
- timer property with property sensor
- property with property actuator and property sensor

The timer property gives the time in seconds while the other options use number of frames.

#### Wait for second key press

There are several options too.

- as long as the timer is running, you are waiting ... otherwise not. This could be sensed with a property change sensor
- remember the wait state (either use build in state system or use a property to remember the state)

#### Do operation

This is up to you

#### Timer exceeds

either the delay sensor pops up or you measure this with a property sensor (greater than mode).

## Example

I choose a delay sensor and the build-in state machine.

State "idle" (waiting for first key press)

[image]

State "waiting" (waiting for second key press)

[image]

Be aware when you have other "breaking" events beside timeout you need to add them too (e.g. pressing another key might break the combo).

## Remarks

Yes, you can implement the same architecture with Python. There are no additional benefits.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I want to make it in python. I'll try using delay sensors since I just know about it. I'll also learn state in python.

Comment: it is the exact same design. If you implement it in Python or not does not matter. See section Remarks